# The tablix ‘Tablix18’ has a detail member with inner members

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

I wanna create rdlc Report with many table but the error is

""The tablix ‘Tablix18’ has a detail member with inner members. Detail members can only contain static inner members.
The tablix ‘Tablix17’ has a detail member with inner members. Detail members can only contain static inner members.""

How can I do to get Report?